# Android isDirectory() always returns false, while file (and directory) is present

Tags: android, file, directory

I have following code:

```
File invoiceFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator + filename);
if (!invoiceFile.isDirectory()) {
}
```

It always returns false, while file is present in specified directory.

`isFile()` and `exists()` also return false.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I do have both permissions Read & Write external storage.
Running it on Android 4.

Comment: Do you have the read external storage permission in your manifest? Are you running on an Android 6.0+ device and target API 23+ or higher? Do you use runtime permissions to request the read external storage permission?

Comment: Are you using "!"? Or simply invoiceFile.exists()?